# Get upload speed from percentage uploaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-upload, performance, nstimer

I want to calculate the speed of a file upload to Dropbox.

Here's the code that I'm currently using:

```
int numberOfCalls = 0;

- (float)getUploadSpeed:(float)currentAmountUploaded {
    numberOfCalls++;
    NSLog(@"called %d times.", numberOfCalls);
    NSLog(@"speed approx. %fKB/sec.", (currentAmountUploaded / numberOfCalls)*1024);
    return (currentAmountUploaded / numberOfCalls)*1024;
}

- (void)startUploadSpeedTest:(NSNumber *)uploadCurrent {

    float uploadedFileSize = [uploadCurrent floatValue];

    NSMethodSignature *signature = [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(getUploadSpeed:)];

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    [invocation setSelector:@selector(getUploadSpeed:)];

    [invocation setTarget:self];
    [invocation setArgument:&uploadedFileSize atIndex:2];
    [invocation invoke];

    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    [[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 invocation:invocation repeats:YES] retain];

    [runLoop run];
    [pool release];
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadProgress:(CGFloat)progress forFile:(NSString *)destPath from:(NSString *)srcPath {
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:srcPath error:nil];
    float fileSize = ((float)[fileAttributes fileSize]/1024/1024);
    float uploadedFileSize = fileSize * progress;

    NSNumber *number = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:uploadedFileSize] autorelease];

    NSThread *timerThread = [[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startUploadSpeedTest:) object:number] autorelease];
    [timerThread start];
}
```

However, the timer isn't called every second, and I'm not sure this is the best way for obtaining the speed.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you compute the speed directly in the uploadProgress-Method?

Here is a pretty simple solution.

```
-(void) restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadProgress:(CGFloat)progress forFile:(NSString *)destPath from:(NSString *)srcPath {
    static NSDate* date = nil;
    static double oldUploadedFileSize = 0;
    if (!date) {
        date = [[NSDate date] retain];
    } else {
        NSTimeInterval sec = -[date timeIntervalSinceNow];
        [date release];
        date = [[NSDate date] retain];
        NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:srcPath error:nil];
        double uploadedFileSize = (double)[fileAttributes fileSize] * progress;
        if (sec) {
            NSLog(@"speed approx. %.2f KB/s", (uploadedFileSize - oldUploadedFileSize )/1024.0 / sec );
        }
        oldUploadedFileSize = uploadedFileSize;
    }

}
```

Note, the first and last speed values may be inaccurate.

Comment: Thank you so much! Couldn't figure out a way to make it work!